# Kill process after running

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

I generate an executable from python script with cxfreeze. It works correctly, but when the running is finished the process continue to live, in fact for example I cannot delete the folder that contains the exe.
How can I stop the program after running?

```
sys.exit(1)
```

doesn't work.

Comment: doesn't work? mayve the `SystemExit` exception is catched? Can you show us your code? Does it work using the python script (without cxfreeze) ?

Comment: weird. I never saw that and would curious to see the code